# Http 503 error in servlet connection

Tags: java, tomcat

I am using the Apache tomcat server for webserver and OPEN NMS server(in separate system). I am modifying the OpenNMS jar file to support our application. But if I want to add some code for Assets to add/modify the Assets table in OpenNMS DB then it is giving "HTTP 503 error". For other module (alarm), the same is working but for Assets it is giving error.

Answer (score 1):

A 503 error is often generated by Tomcat when an exception occurs during processing the request. Something went wrong inside the application -- probably in the code you added. Typically, Tomcat shows you a stack trace in the browser. If not, then simply look at the catalina.out log file in (Tomcat home)/logs and scroll towards the bottom. You should see some stack trace.